# Django Unique properties in admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm building a generic template that will be deployed for several sites, one of the customizing options we'd like to allow would be a custom font for the title text. I'd like to add this property to the admin interface.
Is there a better technique then creating a model for these properties and doing a Model.objects.get() to retrieve 1 instance.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've currently implemented django-chunks from [github](https://github.com/clintecker/django-chunks)
It allows the use of

```
{% load chunks %}
{% chunk "key" %}
```

where the chunk is a key,value set.

I've used this technique to insert "dynamic css", (my admin can provide the css required to upload a custom font)

**Example:**
subtitle_font_css

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "impact";
    src: url('/static/fonts/impact.ttf');
}
</style>
```

subtitle_font

```
font-family: impact;
```

Now for the html:

```
<head>
    {% load chunks %}
    {% chunk "subtitle_font_css" %}
</head>
<body>
    {% load chunks %}
    <span style="{% chunk "subtitle_font %}"> Title </span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a context processor, and only hitting the database on first request, or if you forcefully trigger a reload of the settings. For instance:

```
from project.theme.models import Theme

THEME_SETTINGS = Theme.objects.values().get(id=1) # hits db first request

def theme(request):
    if 'reset_theme' in request.GET: # or some other mechanism
        THEME_SETTINGS = Theme.objects.values().get(id=1) # reset theme settings
    return THEME_SETTINGS
```

To use, just add the context processor to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in your settings. Context processors are fairly simple, they take a `RequestContext` and return a dict used to populate the `RequestContext`.

Comment: Interesting approach, I'll leave the thread open for now to see other opinions.